# Hayes's PROCESS Multicategorical IV

Tags: spss, mediation

I conduct an experimental research which contains 8 conditions (8 different types of fruits, 1=apple, 2=orange, 3=watermelon, 4=banana, 5=strawberry, 6=lemon, 7=pineapple, 8=grape) and use SPSS PROCESS Model 4 for data analysis.

I indicate the multicategorical nature of the independent variable (i.e., 8 conditions) when I run the PROCESS Model 4 and select "indicator" for the multicategorical variable.

Below is the coding of categorical X variable for analysis:
[image]

Based on the above coding, condition 1=apple is set as reference group. Results indicate that X1 and X3 significantly predict the mediator (M). The mediator shows statistically significance to the outcome variable (Y). There are two significant relative indirect effect paths (X1 --> M --> Y and X3 --> M --> Y).

However, if I change the labelling of my conditions in my raw dataset in Excel spreadsheet to 1=strawberry, 2=lemon, 3=pineapple, 4=grape, 5=apple, 6=orange, 7=watermelon, 8=banana (of course I change the labelling of each condition corresponding to the original dataset of the condition by using data sorting function provided by Excel), reference group would now be 1=strawberry. Results of Model 4 show that X1, X5, and X7 significantly predict the mediator (M). The mediator shows statistically significance to the outcome variable (Y). There are three significant relative indirect effect paths (X1 --> M --> Y, X5 --> M --> Y, and X7 --> M --> Y).

My question are: Why the results would be different if I have different labelling assigned to the conditions? Which set of results I should use?

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that in model 1,  X1 represents orange-apple, and X3 represents banana-apple. In model 2, X1 is lemon-strawberry, X5 is orange-strawberry, X7 is banana-strawberry. So the results might be different (assuming you did not make any mistake) because you now have changed the variables (differences wrt strawberries instead of wrt apples). Both results are ok, depending on your research question one model might be better than the other. So, if you have an hypothesis that:

1. orange and banana are better for 'health'
2. this happens through the mediating effect of orange and banana having more vitamin XYZ than apples,

then model 1 is the right one for you, I can imagine. But if the base diet you are comparing to is made of strawberry, then maybe model 2 might be better.

some additions to answer the question "what if I am interested in orange-watermelon?"

first of all, for your question the part M-->Y is irrelevant. you probably did an ANOVA, who told you that X significantly affects M, so you better keep that variable in the model. then you did posthoc tests to understand how X affects M. usually these posthocs are decided a priori based on the research hypothesis. the number of posthocs you can do is infinite! you can ask whether orange is better than watermelon, but also whether 2 oranges are better than 3 watermelons. if you wanna test orange-watermelon, you do not need to recode your variables, i.e. you can still have apple as reference group. you just need to write the contrast differently, like beta_1-beta_2. or 2*beta1-3*beta2

Comment: If condition 1=apple is set as a reference group and I now have 7 groups (X1=orange-apple, X2=watermelon-apple, X3=banana-apple, etc.)

A follow-up question is that: what about other combinations/groups such as orange-watermelon, watermelon-banana, or lemon-grape? I believe there should be many other possible combinations/groups. Will I miss their effect on Y? It looks like I can't examine their effect on Y except that I change the labelling of each condition in my raw dataset based on my research question/hypotheses before running SPSS PROCESS.